# is the vector space of n- forms of an n-manifold equal to the vector space of compactly supported n-forms?

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $\Omega^{n}(M)$ be the real vector space of smooth n-forms of an n-manifold $M$. It is a real vector space of dimension 1. $\Omega^{n}_c(M)$ is the real vector space of compactly supported smooth n-forms on $M$. Since it is a subspace of $\Omega^{n}(M)$, which has dimension 1, shouldn't be equal to the whole $\Omega^{n}(M)$ or to $\{0\}$? But there are n-forms that are not compactly supported.

Comment: oooooohhhh okay

Comment: So I actually confused omega with the vector space of alternating tensors.

Comment: Actually, it is a vector space, but not of dimension $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with your confusion. I think you are misunderstanding the dimension of the vector space you have in each point, and $\Omega^n(M)$ as a real vector space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, for the purposes of your confusion, we can first consider changing "n-form" to "vector field" in order to gain some more concreteness first. The confusion is the same.

Consider the set of vector fields on a manifold $M$, let's call it $V(M)$. It is the set of smooth sections of the tangent bundle $TM$. What we are doing is assigning to each point $x$ of $M$ a point on $T_xM$ in a "smooth" way. This is a real vector space, since we can add two vector fields: we do it by adding in each $T_xM$. The dimension of $T_xM$ is $n$, but not of $V(M)$. It is a different object.

Analogously, in your case, a smooth n-form is a section on the n-th exterior power of the cotangent bundle. In each point, you have a vector space of dimension $1$. But $\Omega(M)$ is not that vector space, it is a different object.

Comment: To expand on the last sentence: the difference here is roughly the same as the difference between $\Bbb R$ and $C^\infty(M)$. You can consider the former as a "1-dimensional vector bundle" over $M$, and the latter is its space of sections. It is, of course, much much bigger.

Comment: In fact, the OP asks a very interesting question: given that both $\Omega ^n (M)$ and $\Omega ^n _c (M)$ are non-trivial $C^\infty (M)$ - modules of rank $1$, and the second is a submodule of the first, must they be identical? In other words, if $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules with $M \subseteq N$, and $\operatorname{rank} M = \operatorname{rank} N$, must we have $M=N$? If not, why not? That's a very good question, even though the OP has formulated it in a wrong manner.